# How await account from web3React?

Tags: reactjs

**Code:**

```
const App = () => {
  const { account } = useWeb3React()

  return (
    {account
      ? <Dasboard/>
      : <HomePage/>
    }
  )

}
```

**Issue:**

The account does not come immediately, but after about half a second, because of this there is a blinking of the interface. While there is no account, the HomePage component is shown for a second, then the Dashboard is shown. How do I fix this? If account false I always must render HomePage.

Comment: Don't show anything until you know if there is an account or not. Then you can show the correct one immediately.

Comment: While there is no account, I need to always show HomePage

Comment: Yes, but if I understand you correctly, there is a brief moment where you don't know. You can create a placeholder loading screen until you know for certain and then use the correct component.

Comment: It's not all so clear-cut. If I insert the loader and try to wait for the account to arrive, the account is undefined twice and the loader remains, the other components are not rendered.

Comment: So your question is really: "How to distinguish if a user has no account or if the account is still being loaded by external library X?"

Comment: I try to reproduce it on codesandbox

Answer (score 0):

you can implement some kind of spinner:

```
const App = () => {

 if(loading) return <Spinner />

  return (
    {account
      ? <Dasboard/>
      : <HomePage/>
    }
  )

}
```

Comment: Yes I thought of that, but the account comes back from the library hook and I can't track its loading

```const { account } = useWeb3React();```

Comment: there is some answer that implements loading functionality [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68345619/how-to-keep-metamask-connection-to-the-ui-persistent-with-web3-react) but i am not much experienced with web3 sorry

Comment: I saw that answer, but thanks anyway!